# Pass value into Terraform variable of type object from the CLI

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a variable declared in my `variables.tf` file that looks like the below:

```
variable "linux_jb_0" {
    description = "Linux jump box settings"
    type = object(
        {
            vm_size  = string
            adm_acct = string
        }
    )
    default = {
            vm_size  = "Standard_A1"
            adm_acct = null
    } 
}
```

I am trying to determine how to pass in a value to the `adm_acct` property of this variable from the command line. I have tried the below but it does not work:

```
terraform apply -var "linux_jb_0={"adm_acct":$account","vm_size":"Standard_A1"}"
```

This command tells me `Variables not allowed`. Are variables truly not allowed to be used in this scenario or do I have the syntax incorrect?

Comment: You cannot interpolate variable values as inputs or defaults for `variable` types. Also, `account` is undefined in this situation, so it would be `null` anyway.

Comment: @MattSchuchard $account is being defined by the shell script that is executing the `terraform apply` command. I have been passing variables into Terraform from the command line using the `-var "tfvariable=$cmdlineVariable"` format for years...just have never done it using a Terraform variable of type `object`.

Answer (score 8):

This syntax worked with Terraform v1.0.0:

```
terraform apply -var "linux_jb_0={\"adm_acct\"=\"$account\",\"vm_size\"=\"Standard_A1\"}"
```

Confirmed that this syntax works going back to Terraform v0.12.31.

Comment: I posted the bounty because I am using HCL2 with packer and ran into a similar issue as well. This solution addressed my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Update answer:

The following should do the trick with escaped double quotes around variable:

```
terraform apply -var="linux_jb_0={"adm_acct":"\"${account}\"","vm_size":"Standard_A1"}"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but tried that and what that does is pass in `$account` explicitly as the value...not the value that is store in `$account`

Comment: I updated my answer. So single quotes would definitely not work evaluate $account. With double quotes around it, it should do the trick

Comment: The double quotes don't work either. Throws the error `Invalid expression`

Comment: @phydeauxman Apologies, I missed the double quotes that need to be escaped in order for variable to be evaluated. Updated answer works 100%

Comment: Still no joy. This `-var="linux_jb_0={"adm_acct":"\"${linux_jb_adm_aact}\"","vm_size":"Standard_A1"}"` is the exact line I used and it says `Variables not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

Just run `terraform plan` & `terraform apply` without the `-var` and make the shell script `export` whatever environmental variables `terraform` may need; for example `export ADM_ACCT=somevalue`. These can then again be accessed with `${var.ADM_ACCT}'`... if required, some helper script can prepare the script to parse (eg. from JSON input), as these exports will always be setup for the shell that runs them, which likely might not be the same shell.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite long after the question, but I've use the following input  for object on windows, and it works.
We never know if it can help someone else :

```
terraform plan -var 'environment_ids={application="""my_app""", scope="""my_scope""", region="""my_region"""}'
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I'm using Terraform 1.3.4 on a Mac and this works fine:

```
terraform plan -var 'healthcheck={protocol="http", port=8000, regional=true}'
```

So key takeaway is only worry about double quotes if the variable or attribute is type=string.